# making special characters optional in regular expression

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I have following requirement:

password must be 6-18 characters and contain at least one letter and one number. Special characters such as @, %, &, # are permitted.

I have created this:

```
^.*(?=.{6,18})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[@%&#]).*$
```

but It accepts other special characters like _ as well and It requires that one of these special characters @%&# must be in string. I want to make this optional. Means if user enters one of these special characters then string should be valid but If user doesn't enter these characters then it should not be invalid. and If user enters any other special character, string should be invalid.

Comment: Why did you tag this `nsregularexpression`?  Is this question about ASP.NET or Objective-C?

Answer (score 6):

As the other responders said, it's the `.*` that's matching those unwanted characters.  The first `.*` shouldn't have been there at all, and the second one should be replaced with a character class.

Or even better, add a `$` to the end of the first lookahead; now it validates both the length and the composition.  The `.*` at the end and the two that were inside the lookaheads are okay because the composition has already been validated.

```
^(?=[A-Za-z0-9@%&#]{6,18}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z]).*$

or, more readably:

^                             # start of string
(?=[A-Za-z0-9@%&#]{6,18})$    # length and composition
(?=.*\d)                      # required digit
(?=.*[A-Za-z])                # required letter
.*                            # go ahead and consume it
$                             # end of string
```

Answer (score 3):

The '.' allows any character beside the newline (\n) so if you omit the last section of your regex it should do what you need:

```
^.*(?=.{6,18})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z]).*$
```

If you want some characters to be not allowed such as the '_' you can put them in a negative look ahead, e.g.

```
^.*(?=.{6,18})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?!.*[_]).*$
```

Will not allow '_' and '*' in the string.

Comment: This one worked. One last thing. Can we somehow disallow all special characters except these 4 ?

Comment: Try this one `^[0-9a-zA-Z@#%&]*(?=.{6,18})(?=[0-9a-zA-Z@#%&]*\d)(?=[0-9a-zA-Z@#%&]*[A-Za-z])[0-9a-zA-Z@#%&]*$` It has the same idea that @A.B.Cade had.

Comment: @user1125955: Why would you disallow any character in a password?

Answer (score 0):

For the length, simply use a string length function.

Then simply test that your input obeys `[0-9],`[A-Za-z]`and`^[0-9A-Za-z@%&#]+$`.

Comment: I want to allow @%&# these characters as well ( although optional )

Comment: Well, this will allow them -- it only tests that there is at least one letter and one digit, that's it. The regexes are _not_ anchored!

Comment: fge I want to allow only these special characters, all other special characters/characters should be disallowed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "." which allows almost everything, use something like:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z@#%&]
```